# how to display Horizon line on camera view image?

Tags: camera

I want to display horizon line on camera view image. how can I do that? It is more convenient for display horizon line in a new image. Could anyone tell me how to do that?

I mean that I want to get the line in any scence, any scence is ok for me. I just want to get the line. To my best wishes, I want to display the horizon line in a spereate image to the rendered one or finished image. And ofcause, the it must be the horizon line in camera view.

Comment: Do you mean you'd like to get line of "existing" horizon (e.g. a plane or something you intend to serve like horizon already) or to have an arbitrary one?

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you want to achieve. Please add a few details to your question to what you want to achieve (horizon of the scene? Horizon in the rendered, finished image, horizon in camera view, etc)

Comment: @MrZak I think horizon line is just the only one line that existed in the image corresponding to the camer view. I just want to get the existing horizon line.

Answer (score 1):

I am not at all sure if that's what you're searching, but if you want to display the middle of the camera, that's done in the camera settings. Just select it and go to the following place:

[image: guides]

If however you need a custom guide like this:

[image: shoot to thrill]

or this:

[image: guide by fractals]

...then there's at least 3 things you can do:

1. Bribe a dev or become one
2. Do serious Python work and write an Addon
3. Make a mesh consisting of edges and place it inside the camera.

Options one and two are fascinating yet option 3 is fast and easy.

[image: home sweet home inside a triangular box thingy]

Just model whatever guide you need out of edges and place the object into your camera. Make sure it's visible from camera view. Put the guide's object origin at the camera origin to avoid relationship lines. Parent the object to the camera. And in the outliner, disable rendering and selection.

[image: hidden and untouchable]

If you want colors, just use a grease pencil line instead. You can edit them similar to a mesh.

[image]

The stroke can be parented to the camera as well.

[image: blue blue blue]

For rendering, I'd probably just create an image of the line with transparent background in Gimp or Blender and then composite it on top of the rest with the Node Editor and an Alpha Over node.

[image: art]

Images usually render faster than most scenes that recalculate stuff for every frame.

Comment: thanks, I did what you suggested, but the line is the dashed line which I want is the solid line. Is there any way?